# В чем разница версий GlassFish 5?

Tags: java, glassfish

На официальном сайте представлено несколько версий для [GlassFish 5](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download)  (`GF5`).

1. Какая разница между ветками `Web Profile` и `Full Platform`? Все равно это `web` сервер, что тогда понимается под полной платформой?
2. Какая разница между `Promoted Build` и `Nightly Build`?

Не призываю переписывать документацию просто подскажите в чем разница на уровне идеи. Зачем было делить и какое предназначение в целом у этих линеек версий? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240056/6125207) показано различие web и full версий.

Nightly Build, собирается, соответственно, еженощно и может содержать больше ошибок\фич, чем Promoted. Последнее, это как-то и по каким-то критериям отдельно выделенная сборка.